# Google's Cloud MySQL shuts down after 15 minutes. Why?

Tags: mysql, cloud, google-cloud-sql

We are using Google's Cloud MySQL service. After 15 minutes it seems to shut down or go to sleep.

This activity directly relates to the settings of "On Demand" and "Per Use" selections. We have ensured these are set to "Always On" and "Package" upon creation of the service.

**What occurs** -
After approximately 15 minutes of inactivity on the MySQL service we attempt to make a query. This first query takes approximately 10 seconds to issue back a response. The following queries respond within normal response times.

---

We are utilizing the **D1 Tier**.

**Possibilities** -
Is this Tier possible to low of resources to make the above settings effective?

---

Any suggestions to ensure the MySQL service with Google is always running and not in some type of idle mode?

Pinging the MySQL server every 14 minutes could be a possibility but seems Google does have the ability to handle this themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I am not able to diagnose the direct problem quickly enough, so I had to move forward. I solved the problem by adding a connection ping every 7 minutes to keep the connection alive.

Hope the below helps someone. This is written within NodeJS. The concept should be universal.

```
var keepAlive = function() {
  pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
    if(err) { console.log(err) }

    connection.ping(function (err) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log('Server responded to ping');
      connection.release();
    });
  });
};

setInterval(function(){keepAlive();}, 420000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try 
In the Edit mode of your instance of MySQL on Google Cloud. Set the Activation Policy to ALWAYS ON